# Wix 3.9 installer - error CNDL0006

Tags: wix, wix3.9

This is (part of) my code:

```
<Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut" Name="MyApp" Description="CATS" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]\CATS.exe" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER">
```

This is the error i'm getting:

> error CNDL0006 : The Shortcut/@WorkingDirectory attribute's value
>   cannot be an empty string. If a value is not required, simply remove
>   the entire attribute.

As you can see, the attribute's value is not an empty string. 
How can i solve this error ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is `INSTALLDIR` set anywhere? Do you have the proper `<Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" ... >` somewhere?

Comment: I see that i do have this:

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MYApp"/>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the same variable name in the attribute as you used to identify the install location.

If your exe is installed in a dir with id X:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="X" Name="MYApp"/> 
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Then use this same X is when specifying the working dir. It seems from your comment that you used the id INSTALLFOLDER in one place but INSTALLDIR in the other. INSTALLDIR is then not specified and will be the empty string, thus the error.

Comment: I have **INSTALLFOLDER** set, not **INSTALLDIR**. And i do have it in both places - where i identify the install location and where i reference it for adding the shortcut. I will add an answer just so my code will be clear.